# PdfBox text extraction not working properly

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

```
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
String text = stripper.getText(document);
```

Extracted text: http://pastebin.com/BXFfMy0z

Problem pdf: http://www.iwb.ch/media/Unternehmen/Dokumente/inserat_leiter_pm.pdf

What can I do to extract correct text from this pdf file?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

*In addition to @karthik27's answer:*

Adobe Reader is fairly good at text extraction and, therefore, generally can be used as an indicator whether text extraction from a given document is possible at all.

Thus, whenever you have a document your own text extraction cannot handle, open it in the Reader and try copying & pasting from it. If that results in garbage, most likely it is [not authored properly for text extraction](http://kb.datalogics.com/articles/FAQ/Why-do-I-get-junk-characters-for-some-PDF-documents-when-extracting-text-using-the-WordFinder-1322829100130?retURL=/apex/knowledgeProduct?c=Document_Processing&k=&lang=en_US&popup=false&lang=en_US), either by mistake or by design.

In case of your document I do get a semi-random collection of invisible and special characters copying and pasting from Adobe Reader like [you did with PDFBox](http://pastebin.com/BXFfMy0z), i.e. garbage. Most likely, therefore, nothing short of OCR will allow text extraction from it.

Comment: It happens so that @karthik27 's 2nd link provides exact answer what to do: "*Fortunately, it's more common for font subsets to leave enough information around for a clever text extractor to use. For example, the glyph names often contain the original character codes: the ASCII code for 'T' is 84, and the font subset might use 'p84' as the glyph name for this character.*" Though character names use 'C' prefix, not 'p'. So, if OP feels strong enough, he can handle it without OCR.

Comment: Well, I think he can manually read and type the text from the document at hand into a text document faster than figuring out those details. But indeed, if it was a really long document or a large, homogeneous collection of documents, such cleverness might be an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is encoding.. The pdf text is encoded in different format.. if you right click on the document and click on document properties.. you can find the encoding. I think the below links will give you more explanation

[link1](http://kb.datalogics.com/articles/FAQ/Why-do-I-get-junk-characters-for-some-PDF-documents-when-extracting-text-using-the-WordFinder-1322829100130?retURL=%2Fapex%2FknowledgeProduct%3Fc%3DDocument_Processing%26k%3D%26lang%3Den_US&popup=false&lang=en_US)
[link2](http://www.glyphandcog.com/textext.html)

Answer (score 0):

The original file should contain mapping to Unicode. This part is absent, thus you have got broken text after extraction.